# VMware webMKS(WMKS) console connection url?

Tags: javascript, vmware, vsphere

I have read "VMware HTML Console SDK Programming Guide" and code following that guide, then meet the problem: What is url connection? 
In guide, url connection has the format: `<ws | wss> :// <host:port>/ <path> /? <authentication info>`, but I don't know what exactly the url is. 
Can anyone help me and give the example about that.

The guide is in: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/html-console/html-console-sdk-100-programmer-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The url should be something like this:  wss://HOST/902;TICKET

The TICKET is a string starts with cst- and also contains the thumbprint information in it. You can get the ticket by making a *acquireMksTicket* call.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VC 5.5 and it looks like wss://VChostName:port/console/authd?<--authentication details>&vmid= &vmName=